# Not able to connect to Organization service even with used correct credentials in CRM dynamics - C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am not able to connect to Organization service even with I have used correct credentials in CRM dynamics - C#
I am able to login from dynamics crm site with same credential.
I am using Microsoft.crm.SDK version 9 and also getting response code 200 with HttpClient as shown below.

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
          client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webApiUrl);
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeader;
          var response = client.GetAsync("WhoAmI").Result;
 }
```

BUT the problem is with Organization service, It is giving me message security exception.
Can you please help me with this, I have tried many solutions from internet but not succeed.
Please find attached photos for exception detail, and feel free if you need more information.

[Connection string I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIrFd.png)

[Error from organization service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn4tn.png)

[Inner exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIVLK.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you are using dynamics 365 version 9.0 online and you are connecting to dynamics using webapi.

You are bit confused here.
There are 2 ways from using c# you can connect to crm.
1. Using webapi. Here you need authentication token and so on.
2. Dynamics 365 (crm assemblies) here you do not need authentication token rather username and password

And you want webapi so in your case no need for organizationservice, once you are connected with your authentication header and so on you can call webapi url for create/retrieve and so on and get your work done.

Some examples here for webapi

https://www.inogic.com/blog/2016/04/set-values-of-all-data-types-using-web-api-in-dynamics-crm-through-c/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/web-api-samples-csharp

https://rajeevpentyala.com/tag/web-api/

Using organization service example of console app

I am not sure where you will be firing your c# but below example of console app will help you

https://www.google.com/amp/s/arunpotti.wordpress.com/2018/02/03/step-by-step-to-connect-dynamics-365-crm-online-v9-x-using-c-console-application/amp/

Edit:

You could also you plugin from XRMToolBox. It is called [codenow](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/TreeCat.XrmToolBox.CodeNow/)
This will definitely solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I want to use Dynamics 365 (crm assemblies) for updating creating records...so for that I think I need organization service.So is there any way to solve this and get workaround.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I have tried same solution as  https://www.google.com/amp/s/arunpotti.wordpress.com/2018/02/03/step-by-step-to-connect-dynamics-365-crm-online-v9-x-using-c-console-application/amp/                                       but still its giving me  error "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail." with inner exception "Authentication Failure". It was generated from code line Guid userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)organizationService.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;

Comment: I searched over internet and found something like it is related to time synchronous between my machine and server?...still I am not sure on this. It me may issue related to security.

Comment: Yes that is an know issue. I would suggest run console application on server itself and see the console log. You should be able to connect.

Comment: Than you brother...Is there any other way like changing credentials or dll version? as I don't have server access so can not check over there.

Comment: Edited answer. Try it. If this helps mark it as solved

Comment: Thank you...I have checked with this tool and it's giving me error 'Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.crm.site.services version 9.0.0.0'

Comment: There are sample examples given on this tool and this shall works, it works for me.

Comment: Thank you...The problem is when I try to make new connection with connection string it is giving me this error, so that is why I think I am not able to see sample code?